# Error in PushWoosh integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I've been trying to integrate PushWoosh in my project, actually I did integrate it successfully and released apps on the appStore. Now I am planning to release very similar app but with different content. I've done the same lately and the PW was working quite fine with each new duplicated target. But recently the duplicated target causing problem. Gives this Error alert at app startup:

```
Title: PushWoosh Error
Description: Your provisioning profile does not have any APS entry. Please make your profile push compatible.
```

I made the profiles Push compatible via the Pushwoosh's auto feature and downloaded then modified profiles and used them for archiving. I'd be very thankful if you guys can point out anything that I need to look at.

[Update]

One thing worths mention that I switched computers while making replica builds. So, in the start all builds are giving the error then at the end after being frustrated I generated whole new distribution certificates for this new computer. Now, with the new certificate and stuff I got my first target pushWoosh ready but then on the the second target gave the same error as above and surprisingly the third target works well with PW. Now I am in a fix that where's what going wrong causing such random errors. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the "aps-environment" string in your mobile provisioning profile? If you don't you  have to recreate it in the Apple Development Portal and then make sure there is such a string in a new profile, and its' value matches the gateway you're using in PW, that is "development" for Sandbox and "production" for Production.

Comment: Spot on man... that was the problem. Though I already had figured out but thanks anyways. It might help someone else in the future. Besides, what I was doing wrong is that I was downloading the profile right after making them push compatible through PW.

Comment: After being frustrated I end up reading Apple's guidelines line by line and at some place stumbled upon "You have to modify the profile in some minor way (for example, toggle an option) for the portal to generate a new provisioning profile. If the profile isn't so “dirtied,” you're given the original profile without the push entitlements." Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a different solution to this problem that I hope will help:

My problem was that the name of my app in Xcode wasn't the same as the App ID I had manually created on the Apple Developer Portal. I have 'Automatically manage signing' turned on in Xcode, so Xcode created an App ID automatically in the Apple Developer Portal called XC com paye...

I followed the process of creating the certificates from scratch, added them to the app ID that Xcode created, and voila! It works.

Hope this helps! :-)